# Creating a new feature from an existing one using decision trees

Tags: decision-trees, machine-learning-model, feature-engineering, data-science-model, performance

Is it possible to create a new feature out of two, or more than two existing features using a decision tree?
If so, how, and can it produce features with good information value that can better help the model?

Comment: Why would you use a decision tree? One tree usually is a weak predictor. What is the problem here: high dimensionality?

Comment: No no, I'm trying to create a new feature, from the top features selected, based on an IV filter. I have seen people create categorical features using a decision tree, but I don't understand the idea. @Peter